# SurfaceView in a Fragment overlays SurfaceView in a different Fragment

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have an Activity and two Fragments. In both of Fragments I have different SurfaceViews. When I switch between Fragments the SurfaceView that was shown first overlays the SurfaceView in the second Fragment.
Do you have any idea how to change the Z order (or anything) of SurfaceView to show the right view depending on Fragment?

Comment: can you capture and share the screen of the issue what you are facing

Comment: Fragment are transparent that is why you are facing this problem.Do one thing in both the xml files of fragment give the parent layout a background colour. This will solve your problem.